# How to set the closed dropdown value on an ng-Options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I'm using angular to manage my select dropdown, from an array.

- The entries in the array itself are all lowercase.
- The "selected" variable to be used elsewhere in the code wants to be lowercase.
- The displayed entries in the dropdown want to be uppercase
- When the dropdown is *closed* it wants to display the currently selected entry (in uppercase) **with the string "VIEWING: " prepended**.

I understand how to achieve the first 3 (by using `myValue.toUpperCase() for myValue in myArrayOfValues`) but I don't even remotely know how to go about achieving the 4th point - either in Angular (ideally) or in raw JS/jQuery

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a combination of:

- https://api.jquery.com/focusin/
- https://api.jquery.com/change/
- https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

HTML:

```
<select name=dropdown size=1>
    <option value="option1">option 1</option>
    <option value="option2" selected>VIEWING: option 2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var dropdown = $('select[name="dropdown"]');

dropdown.focusin(function() {
    var selected = dropdown.find(":selected");
    selected.html(selected.val());
});

dropdown.change(function() {
    updateSelected();
    $(this).blur();
});

dropdown.focusout(function() {
    updateSelected();
});

function updateSelected() {
    var selected = dropdown.find(":selected");
    var html = "VIEWING: " + selected.val();
    selected.html(html);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r89oy2zk/

Comment: Hmm ... I agree that this is closer to what is requested than anything else. But really I don't want the value in the stationary box to change when I open the dropdown. I'm getting the impression that's just not possible though :(